# mapping query results to be aggregated under only one number

Tags: php, sql, arrays, phpexcel

I have a very basic script using a basic query which returns result rows and prints them successfully to an excel worksheet

```
    //Create and run query
    $sql = "
    SELECT Manager, count(*) as Items
      from itemCount
    where start_date >= '2019-01-01'
    group by Manager
    order by Manager";

    $result = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $sql);

    $phpExcel = new PHPExcel;
    $sheet = $phpExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet ->setTitle("Management Numbers");
    $sheet ->getColumnDimension('A') -> setAutoSize(true);
    $sheet ->getColumnDimension('B') -> setAutoSize(true);



    //Create header row
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Manager');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Items');

    $rowCount = 2;

    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)){
        var_dump($row);
        $sheet->setCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['Manager']);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['Items']);

        $rowCount++;
    }

    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel2007");
    $writer->save('Management Numbers.xlsx');
```

Here's the problem:

The query currently returns correct rows in this format:

```
Manager  |  Items
-----------------
12           5
13           2
16           3
11           7
18           4
19           8
22           1
21           7
32           4
53           3
25           5
75           2
```

But each manager reports to a certain department and I want to map this so that I can hard-code and assign managers to departments.

How can I use an array to assign the managers to a department like

```
 1=>12,13,16 
 2=>11,18,19,22,21
 3=>32,53,25,75
```

So that I get a spreadsheet with only the department numbers and the aggregated numbers for it's assigned managers, like so:

```
Manager  |  Items
------------------
1           41
2           91
3           185
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For managers with assigned departaments you can create an array like

```
$manager_array['manager_id'][]='department_id';

$manager_array['1'][]=12;
$manager_array['1'][]=13;
$manager_array['1'][]=16;
```

or

```
$manager_array['1']=array(12,13,16);
```

For get the numbers of managers at every department count the $manager_array['manager_id'] like

```
count($manager_array[1]);
```

You can also extend your itemCount table with department_id column (if possible).

Comment: Thank you, the array makes sense. But once I have the full mapping array built, how  do I change out how it's currently writing to excel? Just change $row to $manager_array?

Comment: Also, There may have been a misunderstanding but I don't want a count of managers at each department, I want to aggregate the items for each manager in that department. My query above returns manager IDs and a count of items for each manager, So if 3 managers are assigned to a department, I want the sum of all the managers' items

Comment: Is an any relation between department with manager at your sql table? I don't know how this data is stored and looks like.